# border-bottom is not occupying the full width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have a menu occupying the full width of the page in medium and larger devices and in smaller devices I want to display the menu items vertically. Im using a grid for this but I also want to have a red border-bottom below the active list item (positioned a the list item bottom) and on hover. But this red border-bottom is not occupying the full width of the list item. Do you know why?

This is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/9o1n8fmm/

Html:

```
<div  style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="MenuList">
          <li><a>Item</a></li>
          <li><a>Item</a></li>
          <li><a>Item</a></li>
          <li><a>Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
}
.MenuList{
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  li{
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 20px 15px 20px 15px;

    a{
      color:#fff;
    }
    &:first-child{
      border-left: 0;
      border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    }
    &:hover{
      border-bottom: 5px solid red;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: because you have given padding in ```li``` element remove that padding and then tell me

Comment: @Ashishsah because padding what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex: 1` to the `li` for it to occupy *all* the available space in the `ul` - see demo below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.MenuList {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.MenuList li {
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px 15px 20px 15px;
  flex: 1;
}

.MenuList li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.MenuList li:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}

.MenuList li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}


}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="MenuList">
          <li><a>Item</a></li>
          <li><a>Item</a></li>
          <li><a>Item</a></li>
          <li><a>Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your LI:

```
     flex: 1 0 auto;
```

or yet simpler: `flex: 1;`

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9o1n8fmm/1/)